# How to compute high order differential?

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives

Let $f: E \to \mathbb{R}$ sending  $x \mapsto \|x\|$ and make some simple hypothesis

- $E$ is a Hilbert Space
- Let's say that the norm $\|\cdot\|$ is derived from a scalar product

So we can easily find the différential: $D\|\cdot\|(x)(h)=\langle x/\|x\|,h\rangle$ with $\nabla{ \|\cdot\|}(x)=x/\|x\| \, (grad)$ as shown below:
http://www.les-mathematiques.net/phorum/file.php?4,file=43281.

Computing the second order differential seems more complicated. Here are two idea [Second differential of the norm in an infinite dimensional Hilbert space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1380151/second-differential-of-the-norm-in-an-infinite-dimensional-hilbert-space). But the common point seems that we focus on the terms that involve $x$. We only play on the gradient and don't pay attention to the entire différential!

So for computing the third derivative can we do a similar thoing: ordering well the terms we identificate the gradient of $D^2(f)(y)$ and find the différential of $\nabla({Df^2})(x)$ ? Can anyone show me in this example how he proceed ? thanks!!

Comment: just apply product rule on $\nabla f$. you obtain a bilinear form, or if you like a linear map from $E$ into $E$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g(x) = \nabla f(x) = x / \|x\|$ for $x\ne 0$.
Then, by product rule we obtain for $h\in E$
$$ Dg(x)h = \frac{h}{\|x\|} - x \langle \frac{x}{\| x \|^3}, h \rangle $$
or
$$ \nabla^2 f(x) = \frac{\|x\|^2 \operatorname{id} - x x^*}{\|x\|^3}, $$
where $\operatorname{id}$ is the identity operator and $x^* = \langle x, \cdot \rangle$ the adjoint of $x$.

Now, let $H(x) = \nabla^2 f(x)$.
For $h\in E$ we have
\begin{align} 
DH(x)h &= 0 h \frac{1}{\|x\|} - \operatorname{id} \langle \frac{x}{\| x \|^3}, h \rangle - \frac{hx^* + xh^*}{\|x\|^3} + xx^* \langle 3\frac{x}{\|x\|^5}, h \rangle.
\end{align}
You can probably factor out $h$ using some duality notation. Like I said, it is ugly.

Comment: So for computing the tird derivative of f we derivate $\nabla^2 f(x) $ ? Isn't it $\nabla^2 f(x) = \frac{\|x\|^2 \operatorname{id} - x x^*}{\|x\|^3},$ ?

Comment: @laurentpincemaille oh yes. My bad. you can go on to higher derivatives. writhing them down might be ugly.

Comment: @laurentpincemaille updated answer to include the third derivative.